# Macbook Pro 15 progression bar halts then circle spins

Tags: snow-leopard, startup, error

We have a Macbook Pro 15 Last 2011. The computer starts to boot, it shows the progression bar, then it disappears and the circle just spins.

[image]

I have tried safe mode and it just spins.

I just ran the hardware test and it returned no problems - I am trying to boot into safemode now

[image]

This screen has been running for 15 minutes now - Eventually the grey bar disappears and it just spins

EDIT:: I booted in startup mode and chose the disk utility - It said the HD was fine :(

EDIT:: I am able to boot from a external thunderbolt drive

Ran in verbose mode. Last couple of lines after rebuilding b-tree:

```
The volume Macintosh HD could not be repaired

launch_msg(): Socket is not connected
```

Comment: Have you the Hardware Diagnostics? Press D during startup.... http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: @JBRWilkinson - Yes I ran the test - no problems - I am running safemode now

Comment: Start in Verbose mode (line by line) to see where it hangs up. (Option+v)

Comment: @Buscar웃 Rebuilding catalog B-tree

Comment: @Buscar It's not ⌥V, it's ⌘V for Verbose boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to boot from external drive, then your boot sector obviously has a problem.

Using the CMD+V key combination will boot in the verbose mode if you care to investigate and know where it hangs.

Using the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> key combination and restoring OS is the best option here.

This keyboard combination only works on Mac OSX 10.7 and later.  If you want to restore the OS on earlier versions, you have to use the installation CD.